# position: sticky to bottom left

Tags: html, css

I have just been playing around in FF32 & Safari 7, with `position: sticky`. And it works perfecly with `top: 0px` or `left: 0px` (to stick horizontally), but it doesn't seem to work when I try `bottom: 0px` or even better, combine `bottom: 0; left: 0` it doesn't set itself to the bottom of the element. This behaviour could be tried out here: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html, by simply changing the `top: 10px` attribut to `bottom: 0`. Is that not supposed to work?

I think it is a valid use-case to stick something to the bottom in the same way as one would want to stick something to the top.
In our case it is, because I am interested in having something sticky on horizontal scroll, but I want this element to be at the bottom of the parent element.

Anyway, any suggestions and extra info are welcome.

Comment: Why dont use 'fixed' instad of sticky?

Comment: @Dexkill because `fixed` elements display even when their parent elements are no longer in view.

Answer (score 17):

```
position: sticky;
bottom: 30px;
```

does work. Keep in mind `sticky` elements are relative to their parent.

http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/QyBMXN?editors=1100 (in Firefox)

In this case, `<section>` (the blue area) is the parent.

It does not work with Stickyfill though https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill#what-it-doesnt

I suggest you play around with it for a bit longer til you get the hang of it.

Let me know if you need a JS plugin that will behave like `position: sticky` without having to use `position: sticky` (can't wait for browser support or a stronger polyfill though).

Comment: If the element you're trying to put the 'sticky' div into is an element with a fixed height then you'll need to add a wrapper div and put the sticky div inside the wrapper at the end.

Answer (score 7):

The way to think about an element with `position: sticky` is as follows:

"The item that has `position: sticky` shall always remain in its normal place inside its parent, UNLESS **said normal place** goes outside of the viewport, in which case sticky item should become fixed relative to the viewport. All bets are off if the parent container also leaves the viewport, in which case the sticky items gets scrolled away with it".

[This Codepen](https://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/QyBMXN?editors=1100) illustrates it really well. Notice how the red box stays in its normal place as long as the parent blue box is in normal view. However, when you scroll such that the red box starts to go out of the viewport, it gets fixed. Finally when the blue parent gets scrolled out of the view entirely, the red box also disappears.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

body {
  height: 3000px;
  padding: 3rem;
}

section {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 30px;
  }
  
div {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci repellat cum totam! Enim, sunt. Numquam voluptate, velit quisquam ipsa molestias laudantium odit reiciendis nisi corporis voluptatibus, voluptatum sunt natus, accusantium magnam consequatur fugit officiis minima voluptatem consequuntur nam, earum necessitatibus! Cupiditate ullam repellendus, eius iure voluptas at commodi consectetur, quia, adipisci possimus, ex mollitia. Labore harum error consectetur officiis aut optio, temporibus iste nobis ducimus cumque laudantium rem pariatur. Ut repudiandae id, consequuntur quasi quis pariatur autem corporis perferendis facilis eius similique voluptatibus iusto deleniti odio officia numquam tenetur excepturi, aspernatur sunt minima aut fugiat ipsam. Ea nesciunt, amet fugit facere similique dolor nam tempora perferendis aut fugiat non, ex pariatur excepturi odio aspernatur libero saepe ducimus rem magni cumque. Laboriosam nisi fuga accusantium quos qui? Maiores ratione aliquam eos odio eius molestiae nesciunt exercitationem dolor perspiciatis quam. Necessitatibus rem nihil ad culpa, tenetur iusto consectetur rerum, delectus neque? Error, quas, eaque! Quibusdam voluptas expedita possimus consequatur accusantium distinctio, esse quisquam, ipsa blanditiis, officia perferendis et? Iste, nam optio vero earum tenetur voluptatibus modi a, odit aliquid eos corporis nulla saepe vel neque voluptate ratione, facilis quo sed nisi voluptates nostrum dolor. Non mollitia dignissimos laudantium quos libero nisi, nobis harum, asperiores soluta reprehenderit doloremque ipsa id unde voluptates beatae deserunt. Minima repellendus ipsam molestias veritatis pariatur nobis nihil, alias quasi, esse, aspernatur saepe beatae, hic consequatur. Sit sequi, libero quisquam quibusdam fuga tempore ab molestiae praesentium, necessitatibus, vero odio ullam qui non totam voluptas reprehenderit ad neque voluptate. Nam atque impedit ducimus, dolore reiciendis delectus inventore beatae cumque. Magni, id quos officiis soluta consequatur nam quis, modi fugit adipisci vel autem dolorum iusto cumque, libero reprehenderit amet doloremque voluptatem sunt sapiente reiciendis omnis, similique nulla enim. Autem repellendus, illo eveniet recusandae quae quibusdam itaque, delectus, consequatur provident vitae vero magnam repudiandae fugit, placeat sapiente! Omnis, possimus natus obcaecati sunt harum impedit, veniam quae numquam cum eos. Suscipit nihil totam itaque odio assumenda nemo? Eos iusto voluptas, consectetur sit totam velit fuga ea impedit laboriosam, dignissimos neque ipsum! Nostrum, recusandae. Autem sit aperiam culpa neque quaerat, voluptatibus repellendus. Magnam voluptatem illo quidem sapiente, nemo neque temporibus unde harum mollitia sit dignissimos eligendi accusantium, deserunt numquam, recusandae aperiam iure vero tenetur ea suscipit. Necessitatibus vel, omnis praesentium pariatur officia! Odio maxime dolor vitae ab deleniti et accusantium, iure molestiae eaque soluta sequi, autem, quae ex labore hic dicta temporibus quibusdam animi modi qui necessitatibus nulla. Perspiciatis molestiae architecto culpa quaerat amet fuga, fugiat laboriosam tempore at adipisci, tempora laborum ducimus alias corporis beatae dolor repellendus reiciendis aut cum. Quos enim quae dolores voluptates deleniti est eum beatae impedit unde quidem cumque, labore, quod a asperiores tempora vel blanditiis? Facere corporis mollitia vitae! Exercitationem esse perferendis, et aliquid iste saepe, quos, qui dolore est facere porro. Sapiente nesciunt, ad nostrum hic optio omnis libero autem minus eius, perferendis numquam adipisci corporis nisi ipsa assumenda possimus repudiandae distinctio vel accusamus quam animi esse eos natus pariatur. Molestiae in temporibus ipsum, eveniet itaque minus facilis magnam corporis amet, aspernatur ducimus iste quis numquam laudantium saepe optio nam nisi dolore necessitatibus perferendis hic non ea labore. Impedit rerum laudantium amet aperiam. Debitis tenetur veniam molestiae ab labore maxime incidunt iste commodi recusandae, adipisci obcaecati, molestias placeat aperiam atque, dolorum facere quae nesciunt. Facere aspernatur dolore consequatur tempora veritatis qui et eos quo voluptatum ipsum nemo rerum debitis nostrum, atque ratione aliquam nulla cumque aperiam officiis? Corporis a sunt, quis vel, quae molestias vitae recusandae magni! Nostrum animi totam dolore nemo voluptatem? Nihil consequuntur corrupti quaerat quis dolorum! Culpa, at quibusdam, saepe quas accusamus sequi tempore molestiae perferendis error fugiat, in totam laboriosam. Mollitia necessitatibus eius nisi, blanditiis rem commodi doloremque dicta, hic cumque quod possimus, obcaecati nesciunt deserunt. Vel id quas aliquam, fugiat repellendus perferendis voluptate consectetur deleniti cumque harum odit dolores ducimus facere? Mollitia qui dolore ut quod facere, recusandae repellendus debitis minus aliquid delectus inventore numquam ipsam fugit doloribus, voluptatum, earum eveniet ipsa, impedit fuga! Illo ipsa dolor id enim facere ipsam similique consectetur porro sequi ea perspiciatis soluta provident, ex amet nulla quos sit. Rerum nam, odit dignissimos! Delectus, corporis perspiciatis magni tempore praesentium dolorem magnam architecto earum animi, vero, obcaecati alias distinctio quae eligendi eos doloremque assumenda. Neque temporibus doloremque, natus deserunt ipsam repellendus. Dolorum consequuntur culpa esse modi adipisci, rem natus at fuga id, architecto delectus! Culpa quaerat nulla magnam sint repudiandae, impedit quisquam iure illum, natus at nesciunt fuga obcaecati excepturi fugiat ea sed repellendus repellat aliquid vel, sunt dolores quae. Omnis nulla soluta natus consequuntur tempore, in esse autem reprehenderit cum totam fugit voluptate libero hic asperiores perspiciatis a, odio voluptatibus non alias inventore delectus impedit praesentium doloribus. Veritatis qui adipisci quisquam voluptates, similique consequatur repudiandae dignissimos accusantium rerum beatae fuga inventore. Sequi soluta maxime facere laudantium sint quae ab, dolores provident doloremque maiores quo eaque commodi veritatis, eligendi illo ipsum. Suscipit, veniam, cumque quidem, distinctio debitis magnam nesciunt dolore reiciendis minus accusantium quod ullam eaque magni. Adipisci debitis a, repellat suscipit doloribus officiis asperiores vero veritatis aliquam praesentium nihil corrupti, ipsam. Quae esse hic fugit, in harum illum laboriosam odio mollitia at dolor nam quisquam aperiam quidem error vero voluptatibus, quos dolorem ratione odit illo libero unde sunt distinctio rerum! Repellat omnis dolorum fuga dolor, molestias earum. Iure, repellendus quae nostrum temporibus odio ad. Nihil quidem enim unde nesciunt, velit esse eveniet nisi architecto ad perferendis obcaecati eum iste ipsum eligendi ut necessitatibus veritatis officiis minus non laborum. Tempore explicabo nostrum nihil. Sed eius, iure nisi saepe. Neque eaque, consectetur nostrum aliquam amet praesentium, dicta excepturi ducimus voluptatibus illum consequatur, rerum veniam omnis eos enim. At asperiores, soluta sapiente amet. Ipsum in sint iusto, cumque possimus iure quia fugiat. Facere ratione consequuntur deleniti nisi, nostrum esse. Et amet deserunt unde aliquid, magni, incidunt fugiat illo neque consequatur eum cum, alias repellendus odit voluptate. Hic ducimus, quidem, excepturi delectus rerum placeat illo exercitationem nesciunt natus voluptatum modi sequi consectetur praesentium quae eaque mollitia! Architecto excepturi atque, molestias natus.
  </p>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height of the sticky element then you can use something like this:

```
.sticky-element {
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

This would also work with Stickyfill. Not sure about browser support though.

Comment: thats not too bad actually!! but rather than `calc` i'd use a negative margin top or translate. if you consider to use `sticky` anyway, those should work in the desired browsers.

Comment: This would be a great way - but unfortunately for mobile devices they've become too clever for their own good with hiding toolbars as you scroll - while 100vh stays the same and so things can end up off the page when you actually test on a device.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #9588c170;
  /* , */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
  overflow: auto;
}

.sticky {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #9588c1;
  /* , */
  position: sticky;
  left: 1000px;
  top: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.sticky-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 100vh; // push it to the bottom from top
  transform: translateY(-100%); // move it up again depending on its own height
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

with the following html:

```
<div id="bottom-left">I'm in the bottom left!</div>
```

and the following css:

```
#bottom-left {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

you should have a sticky div in the bottom left corner of the page

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wjxws9hy/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The only difference between this and `sticky`, is that the element doesn't move when you scroll the parent div. With playing around a bit longer I think it is more an issue of how Firefox is implementing `position: sticky`

Comment: If you don't want it to move use `position: fixed;` if you want it to move, use `position: absolute;`